# Show accordion on mobile devices and tab on others

Tags: angular, typescript, ngx-bootstrap, ngx-bootstrap-accordion

There are multiple pages in my application that use ngx-tabs (https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/tabs), the tabs do not fit well on mobile devices, so on mobile, I want to show ngx-accordion (https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/accordion) instead of tabs. I could achieve this functionality using angular breakpointobserver, but for a particular page. I need to use this across application and was trying to figure out how to write a custom directive or a generic component, that is reusable.

abc.component.html:

```
    <div>
      <tabset *ngIf="tabs">
        <tab heading="Basic title" id="tab1">Basic content</tab>
        <tab heading="Basic Title 1">Basic content 1</tab>
        <tab heading="Basic Title 2">Basic content 2</tab>
      </tabset>

    <accordion *ngIf="!tabs">
      <accordion-group heading="Basic title">
            Basic content
      </accordion-group>
      <accordion-group heading="Basic title 1">
           Basic content 1
      </accordion-group>
      <accordion-group heading="Basic title 2">
           Basic content 2
      </accordion-group>
      </accordion>
    </div>
```

abc.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, ElementRef } from "@angular/core";
import { BreakpointObserver, Breakpoints } from '@angular/cdk/layout';

@Component({
  selector: "app-abc",
  templateUrl: "abc.component.html"
})
export class AbcComponent implements OnInit {
  tabs: boolean = true;

  constructor(private observer: BreakpointObserver) {
    observer.observe([Breakpoints.Small, Breakpoints.Handset, Breakpoints.HandsetPortrait, Breakpoints.HandsetLandscape]).subscribe((result) => {
      if (result.matches) this.tabs = false;
      else this.tabs = true;
    });
  }


  ngOnInit(): void {
  }


}
```

Basically I need something like this,

```
<my-tab>
  <my-tab-item heading="Basic title"> Basic content </my-tab-item>
  <my-tab-item heading="Basic title1"> Basic content 1</my-tab-item>
  <my-tab-item heading="Basic title2"> Basic content 2</my-tab-item>
</my-tab>
```

which gets converted to `<tab>` or `<accordion>` based on a breakpoint.

Thank you!

Comment: You had the right idea? What went wrong with the other implementation? You just need to wrap it in a component and reuse that elsewhere. Unless I'm missing something?

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this goal and get highly reusable components with a few directives and components.

First, lets create a couple structural directives to help out with encapsulating the break point observer logic, so that we can use it where ever it's needed:

```
import {Directive, TemplateRef, ViewContainerRef, OnDestroy} from '@angular/core';
import { BreakpointObserver, Breakpoints, BreakpointState } from '@angular/cdk/layout';
import {Subscription} from 'rxjs'

const MOBILE_STATES = [Breakpoints.HandsetLandscape,Breakpoints.HandsetPortrait];
// base directive that implements the breakpoint observer logic and renders accordingly
abstract class BreakPointObserverDirective implements OnDestroy {
  private hasView = false;
  private sub: Subscription;

  constructor(private tmp: TemplateRef<any>, private viewContainer: ViewContainerRef, private observer: BreakpointObserver, showMobile: boolean) {
    this.sub = this.observer.observe(MOBILE_STATES).subscribe(({matches}) => {
      if ((matches && showMobile) || (!matches && !showMobile)) {
        this.render()
      } else {
        this.clear()
      }
    })
  }

  render() {
    if (!this.hasView) {
      this.viewContainer.createEmbeddedView(this.tmp);
      this.hasView = true;
    }
  }

  clear() {
    if (this.hasView) {
      this.viewContainer.clear();
      this.hasView = false;
    }
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.sub.unsubscribe()
  }
}

// implementation for mobile
@Directive({
  selector: '[ifMobile]'
})
export class IfMobileDirective extends BreakPointObserverDirective {
  constructor(tmp: TemplateRef<any>, viewContainer: ViewContainerRef, observer: BreakpointObserver) {
    super(tmp, viewContainer, observer, true)
  }
}

// implementation for web
@Directive({
  selector: '[ifWeb]'
})
export class IfWebDirective extends BreakPointObserverDirective {
  constructor(tmp: TemplateRef<any>, viewContainer: ViewContainerRef, observer: BreakpointObserver) {
    super(tmp, viewContainer, observer, false)
  }
}
```

which you could use in your templates like this:

```
  <tabset *ifWeb>
    <tab heading="Basic title" id="tab1">Basic content</tab>
    <tab heading="Basic Title 1">Basic content 1</tab>
    <tab heading="Basic Title 2">Basic content 2</tab>
  </tabset>

<accordion *ifMobile>
  <accordion-group heading="Basic title">
        Basic content
  </accordion-group>
  <accordion-group heading="Basic title 1">
       Basic content 1
  </accordion-group>
  <accordion-group heading="Basic title 2">
       Basic content 2
  </accordion-group>
</accordion>
```

it's basically the logic you already have, but encapsulated in a structural directive. You could extend this / get more creative depending on your needs.

Now to get the specific component wrapper around an accordion / tabset that uses these directives... we'll need another directive and a component (note, I'm using material tabs / accordions, but any component library SHOULD work similarly, but I've never used the particular lib you're working with, don't know how well implemented it is):

```
import {Directive, TemplateRef, Component, ContentChildren, QueryList, Input} from '@angular/core';
// directive to find the template to render and accept input like header
// this is where you'd match the parts of the component API you need to mirror
@Directive({
  selector: '[mobileSwitchContent]'
})
export class MobileSwitchContentDirective {
  @Input() header: string;

  constructor(public tmp: TemplateRef<any>) { }
}

// component that finds content directives and implements needed template
@Component({
  selector: 'mobile-switch',
  template: `
    <mat-accordion *ifMobile>
      <mat-expansion-panel *ngFor="let c of content">
        <mat-expansion-panel-header>
          <mat-panel-title>
            {{c.header}}
          </mat-panel-title>
        </mat-expansion-panel-header>
        <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="c.tmp"></ng-container>
      </mat-expansion-panel>
    </mat-accordion>

    <mat-tab-group *ifWeb>
      <mat-tab *ngFor="let c of content" [label]="c.header">  
        <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="c.tmp"></ng-container>
      </mat-tab>
    </mat-tab-group>
  `
})
export class MobileSwitchComponent {
  @ContentChildren(MobileSwitchContentDirective)
  content: QueryList<MobileSwitchContentDirective>
}
```

I THINK the appropriate template for your library would be:

```
<tabset *ifWeb>
  <tab *ngFor="let c of content" [heading]="c.header">
    <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="c.tmp"></ng-container>
  </tab>
</tabset>

<accordion *ifMobile>
  <accordion-group *ngFor="let c of content" [heading]="c.header">
    <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="c.tmp"></ng-container>
  </accordion-group>
</accordion>
```

which allows something pretty close to your intended usage:

```
<mobile-switch>
  <ng-template mobileSwitchContent header="First">
    Content 1
  </ng-template>
  <ng-template mobileSwitchContent header="Second">
    Content 2
  </ng-template>
</mobile-switch>
```

You need the ng-template tags with the directive to allow template injection. The issue is that we can't use ng-content here like we normally would because we're projecting content into different components, so we need this work around. a little messier, but effective none the less.

you MAY want some method of coordinating the selected tab / expanded accordion element in the event of screen size changes, but that will be very lib specific and maybe not needed if your only concern is differentiating between mobile and web.

Big benefit of this approach is that you can use the structural directives where ever you need them, and you're not just constrained to tabs or accordions.

blitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9-material-starter?file=src%2Fapp%2Fmobile-switch.ts